# Alignment issue in Meshlab

Tags: alignment, meshlab

I am trying to align three 3D scans  of a bucket in Meshlab. I open the PLY files and click Align, then set one file as base mesh and then choose one of the other files and click Point Based Glueing. This should open up a split view of the two scans that allows me to pick four points. However, I only get the different scans on top of each other and not the split view. This makes it impossible to pick four corresponding points on the different scans - how do I get the split view? I work on a Macbook Air 11 inc from mid 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can split the view with the Align tool.

For aligning multiple layers, you can make only the base layer and layer you want to align visible in the Align Tool Window. Select the layer you want to align and locate 4 points. Align. Then make the next layer you want to align visible and repeat the process.

Comment: I don’t believe that’s what the OP meant. I’m in the same situation. All the tutorials I see on YouTube show that when clicking on “point based glueing”, a new window opens, where we see two meshes side by side. Then, one can rotate them to a similar position, and proceed with picking the points. Well, when I click In “point based glueing” a new window also opens, but the meshes *are NOT side by side.* They are on top of each other. Which makes picking one or the other a guessing game. And the points picking absolutely impossible, as it picks them in alternate meshes...

Comment: I’m doing this on my MBP retina which can’t use my eGPU at the moment due to Apple’s not releasing Nvidia drivers. I‘ll try again on my windows install, something tells me it will work there...

Answer (score 0):

After trying the current release and latest beta, I sadly gave up and went back to the last version available on sourceforge (1.33).